# blocks and pages missing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, blocks, magento2.1.5

Suddenly Magento does not display any blocks anymore in the frontend.
Also in the backend under `content`, `blocks` and `pages` are missing.
I flushed my cache but there is no change.
Additionally there is nothing in the error logs.
They are still saved to the database `cms_block` table and flagged as `is_active`.

What could be wrong? Did I change some setting that can cause this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-.-

Just after asking I suddenly find it myself.
For some unknown reason the module `Magento_CMS` was disabled.
This leads to no error but a missing `pages` and `blocks`.